# Using python's RegEx {m,n} operation, but using variables for m and n

Tags: python, regex

I want to specificy a global min and max variable to use in a regular expression checking ID validity.

For example, set variables

```
min=8 
max=16
alphanumeric input
```

Then the expression I want Python to interpret is

```
r'\w{8,16}\Z'
```

but I want to use the variables min and max rather than hardcoding the numbers into the expression.

Answer (score 6):

There's no builtin facility for this, but you can build the regexp using string interpolation.  For example,

```
regexp = r"\w{%d,%d}\Z" % (minimum, maximum)
```

Of course there are many other ways to build the regexp you want.  The point is that you have to build it yourself :-)

BTW, please don't use the names `min` and `max`.  They're builtin functions, and using the same names for variables will confuse people - including, sometime later, you ;-)

Comment: thanks for the response, min and max were just for exemplification purposes

Answer (score 2):

You can build regex dynamically:

```
regex = r'\w{{{},{}}}\Z'.format(minimum, maximum)
```